# Is there a way of putting two pivot tables together?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office

So I've got two tables - one that hold premium data for insureds and one that holds claims data for insureds.

The commonality between them is a Deal number (D #).

On the premium table each Deal may have several layers though, so you could have Deal 1234 Layer 1 as this table shows (note deal # 11517 which has two layers):

```
D # Layer   Annual Premium
3414    1    $320,000 
9742    1    $632,454 
16126   1    $675,000 
21795   1    $2,100,000 
5233    1    $165,756 
5849    3    $611,538 
23785   1    $1,770,833 
11517   1    $840,000 
11517   2    $135,400 *****
```

Then you have the claims table which looks like this (note deal 11517 is only listed once, but it's very possible for each deal to have multiple claims - see: 16535):

```
Deal Yr D#  Paid Indemnity  Paid Expense    Incurred
2007    16535    $2,375,000      $162,634    $2,537,634 
2007    16535    $7,125,000      $-      $7,125,000 
2006    10194    $3,839,575      $66,967     $3,906,541 
2006    11517    $685,940    $124,139    $810,079 
2006    13465    $2,126,242      $-      $2,126,242 
2006    11412    $10,000,000     $15,709     $10,015,709 
2006    12313    $85,525     $-      $85,525 
2006    13688    $6,216,817      $100,576    $6,317,393 
2006    13942    $236,669    $17,317     $253,986
```

So the question is, how do I put these table together without duplication. I've tried doing a vlookup on deal # but I end up getting duplicate claims figures for deals with multiple layers, or I get multiple premium figures if I go the other way.

I've tried making a premium table pivot to get a rolled up premium per deal # and a claims pivot to get a rolled up claims figure for deal #, but I don't know how to get them both on the same sheet... any thoughts?

Comment: I'd recommend creating a D# bridge table in PowerPivot, but what do you want the combined table to look like?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I'm not entirely sure how to do that, but I want the combined table to have all those columns (including others that I've hidden for this purposes) and the D# will have total premiums and total #s for claims.

So deal 11517 will be in there once with a rolled up premium of 975,400 and the totals for whatever the claims figs are. I don't care about multiple layers and multiple claims. I want a one to one - one deal number total - with one set of figures for claims for that deal #

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Copy and paste your Claims table and then go choose Remove Duplicates under the Data tab. Choose the `D#` column only. This will give you a table with unique deal numbers.

Now delete the other columns and replace them with `SUMIFS` formulas. E.g.

```
=SUMIFS(Claims[Paid Indemnity],Claims[D '#],[@[D '#]])
=SUMIFS(Claims[Paid Expense],Claims[D '#],[@[D '#]])
=SUMIFS(Claims[Incurred],Claims[D '#],[@[D '#]])
```

Add one more column for the `Annual Premium` and use the appropriate formula:

```
=SUMIFS(Premiums[Annual Premium],Premiums[D '#],[D '#])
```

---

If you want to connect these tables and use them in pivot tables, then create a table with just the unique deal numbers and then load all three tables into your data model and create relationships like this:

[image: Bridge Table]

Comment: That's a good suggestion, and I'm going to give it a go - but won't removing duplicates based on the D# column remove entries that also have unique data in them?

See deal 16535 - the deal # is duplicate, but the rest of the data is unique

Comment: @Kevin You can select which columns it considers when removing duplicates. Select only the D# column in the dialogue box.

Comment: yes but what I'm saying is doing that will remove entries that are unique. That's the overall problem I am having. They share a D# which is indeed duplicate, but the claims values are different.

It's a one to many relationship. There can be one Deal # with many claims against it. Removing the duplicate deal #'s will remove all the other claims...

Like I said - go up and look at 16535 - the deal # is duplicate, but the Paid indemnity, paid expesne values are different. If I removed duplicates, it will get rid of one of those deal #s.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, it would remove those duplicate rows. But when you put the formulas in it would add them together into a single row. If that's not what you wanted, then I must have misunderstood what you are asking.